# Rails form_for setting options and setting selected option

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, select, indexing, form-for

Another simple question i'm sure so sorry in advance but i cant seem to find a solution to what i am trying to do.

I have form with a select field (vehicle_size) that i want to populate with all existing options that are currently in the database for records that have vehicle_size set. I also want to set the selected option to whatever the option in the database is currently set to (if set) but i guess the problem that i am having is the reason that this value isn't being set already.

I currently have this code:

```
<%= f.select(:vehicle_size, @models.index_by {|m| m.vehicle_size}, :selected => :vehicle_size) %>
```

which is populating the select options correctly but in my new and edit pages (both using this form) the select menu is blank even though currently all records are be set to one of the existing options (vehicle_size may actually be blank for some records in future).

If i then select an option from the menu and save the record the vehicle_size option has a strange value. something along the lines of :

```
#<Model:0x007fd13e6c3790>
```

I'm pretty sure i'm using index_by in the wrong way so some pointers on what i'm missing would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters of `f.select` are: `attribute_name`,`option_tags`,`options`.
`option_tags` is supposed to be a string of html option tags.
There are some helpers to construct such a string from i.e. an array of values, a collection etc.: `options_for_select`, `options_from_selection_for_select`.

You have to use one of these helpers.

You can get the existing `vehicle_size`es with:

```
Model.pluck(:vehicle_size).uniq
```

so your select could look like:

```
<%= f.select :vehicle_size, options_for_select(Model.pluck(:vehicle_size).uniq,@model.vehicle_size) %>
```

See the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags) on form helpers.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks. I really need to get my head around searching for the correct terms and spend some time learning more Ruby and Rails so thanks for your help.